# Изучение C++ и Xcode(Mac OS)

Tags: xcode, objective-c, c++

Добрый день.
Вопрос неоднозначный, но буду благодарен за совет. Я хочу изучать мобильную разработку под apple но щас нет денег для покупки нормального оборудования, чтобы не терять время хочу пока изучать C++, так как имею слабое представление об ООП. Да и Objective C полностью совместим с С++. 
Вопрос: есть ли смысл в таком подходе?
Если да то посоветуйте материалы(книги, видео) по изучению С++.
Благодарю.

Comment: @Ruslan1987 не изучайте С++ по видео. Только зря потратите время. Это не тот язык, который можно выучить по видеоурокам из Ютуба

Answer (score 1):

ObjectiveC как бы не полностью совместим с C++, точнее сказать для понимания ООП лучше освоить что-нибудь полегче, например java или C#. Так как для начинающего программиста плюсы, будет сложно и долго изучать. Лично я, пересел с Java на ObjectiveC, можно сказать без проблем. А для начального изучения ObjectiveC хватит и винды с виртуальной машиной. В этой группе есть видео и книги по ObjectiveC http://vk.com/xcoderus

Comment: Пробовал ставить себе виртуальную машину, но постоянно какието проблемы возникают, не хочет ставится. Как я понял проблемы из-за того что у меня AMD стоит. Запускал на виртуал боксе.

Comment: Да у хакинтоша могут быть проблемы с AMD, и еще процессор должен поддерживать виртуализацию.

Comment: Если сильно захотеть можно поискать сборку для AMD.

Comment: Изучал плисы изначально, отличный язык для понимания принципов ООП.

Answer (score 0):

если говорить точно, то Obj-c вообще не совместим с c++, с ним совместим obj-c++ (файлы с расширением .mm и компилит их вроде другой компилятор ) и используется он реально не так уж часто, в основном - если надо написать прослойку к уже имеющемуся плюсовому коду или какому-то плюсову функционалу, например, вектору интов (в obj-c нет своих динамических массивов, так что если он нужен, приходится либо возиться с malloc/realloc/free, либо задействовать плюсовые контейнеры, либо преобразовывать числа в NSNumber)

если хочется именно поучиться obj-c, можно попробовать посмотреть что там есть у [gnustep](http://www.gnustep.org/) или покапаться с клангом, но оба варианта ИМХО можно рассматривать только как временные

Answer (score 0):

В чем проблема поставить на виртуалку OS X, и в симуляторе смотреть результат работы программы?

Comment: Та колупался долго с виртуал боксом, не смог запустить.

Comment: используй VMWare, на всем известном трекере даже готовые образы OS X под него лежат